# How to schedule Spark jobs

Tags: azure, pyspark, scheduling

I'm using Azure services for running my pyspark jobs. Below are my steps:

1. I'm created Docker image for my pyspark job.
2. I'm calling AKS for my resource allocation

What I need is that I want to schedule my job(Should run on a specific days and month).  What would be the better option for scheduling as I'm new to Azure services.

### Update

1. I have created my spark jobs which are running on pods of AKS.
2. Now I want to schedule those pods on a particular frequency (no restrictions on time selection).

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add more detail about the steps you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure since your question is not very clear, but you may be looking to run Cron Jobs in K8S: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

Comment: Heyy what I meant to say is that I my spark jobs are running as pods on AKS and I want to schedule those pods on a particular day with a particular time. I shouldn't have any restriction on scheduling

Answer (score 0):

For scheduling your Spark jobs like Cron job or something, something like Apache Airflow will do the trick. Try researching into it. It's one of the best scheduling framework written in Python. Its code-based, meaning you have to code the entire flow in python and you will be presented with a neat DAG representing your scheduled tasks!

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html